# Как вставить/сосчитать значения БД через gorm на golang?

Tags: postgresql, golang

Начал использовать gorm+postresSQL - выполняю тупо по инструкции, но выдаёт ошибки

```
type MyList struct {
   Id uint64
   Name  string   
   IsTrue bool
}
```

подключил

```
"github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
_ "github.com/lib/pq"


db, err := gorm.Open("postgres", "user=Roman password=Roman dbname=DB1  sslmode=disable")  
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("error: %v\n", err)
   }
   db.DB()


   todo := MyList{Id:8888, Name: "Новое имя", IsTrue:false}

   var me MyList
     db.Where("Name = ?", "Новое имя").First(&me)
     fmt.Println(me)

   db.Create(&todo)

   db.NewRecord(todo)
```

-----он выругался

> [35m(pq: отношение "my_lists" не существует)[0m [33m[2016-02-01
>   18:58:50][0m [31;1m [0m
>
> [35m(pq: отношение "my_lists" не существует)[0m [33m[2016-02-01
>   18:58:50][0m [31;1m [0m

И кто-то знает, как получить айди вставленной строки через gorm? или мне сразу айдишник хранить в переменной +1 и вставлять эту переменную? (обычно как бы так узнавал `"INSERT INTO test(value) VALUES($1) RETURNING id"`) , но в gorm-е пока не оч разбираюсь.

Comment: Первое решил. Таблица иначе называлась . Создал db.CreateTable(&MyList{})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
todo := MyList{Name: "Новое имя 2", IsTrue:false}
db.Create(&todo)
fmt.Println(todo.Id)
```